# How to store image width as a number in a variable with xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to store an image width as a number so I can add a class value to the figure wrapper so I can control the image placement with css, (small, medium, or large image).

This is my xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <section>
        <figure class="informalfigure">
            <img src="../images/image-fpo-1.png" alt="" width="250" height="800"/>
        </figure>
        <figure class="informalfigure">
            <img src="../images/image-fpo-2.png" alt="" width="650" height="800"/>
        </figure>
        <figure class="informalfigure">
            <img src="../images/image-fpo-3.png" alt="" width="1250" height="800"/>
        </figure>
    </section>
</root>
```

This is my xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

<xsl:variable name="small-image">
    <xsl:number value="200"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="medium-image">
    <xsl:number value="500"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="large-image">
    <xsl:number value="1000"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="figure">
    <xsl:variable name="classvalue" select="@class"/>
    <xsl:variable name="img-width" select="number(img[@width])"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="number($img-width) > number($large-image)">
            <figure class="{$classvalue} large">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </figure>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="number($img-width) > number($medium-image)">
            <figure class="{$classvalue} medium">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </figure>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="number($img-width) > number($small-image)">
            <figure class="{$classvalue} small">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </figure>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <figure class="{$classvalue} missedit" width="{$img-width}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </figure>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The variable "img-width" is causing the hangup. I clearly have something wrong there. How would I go about storing the image width as a number variable so my test will work? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks, Jon

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
<xsl:variable name="img-width" select="number(img[@width])"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="img-width" select="number(img/@width)"/>
```

because you store in variable "image width" not "image data"